# Start-Marker from geojson polyline

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

i have a map with some walking- and bike-routes and popups with a few details an a pic. Now i want to set a marker on the first vertex of a geojson polyline, but i cant find out how. Btw. i´m new to leaflet/mapbox, and i put my map togehter from code snippets.
[Here is the map now:](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57482/much/index.html)

This is how i create the polylines now. I call them via layercontrol.

```
var mtb = L.geoJson(radjs, {
filter: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
        // If the property "underConstruction" exists and is true, return false (don't render features under construction)
        return feature.properties.typ === 'mtb';
    }
    return true;
},
style: {
    "color": '#6699cc',
    dashArray: '',
    "weight": 4,
    "opacity": 0.6
},    onEachFeature: onEachFeature2}).addTo(rad);
```

Thank you for your help,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a Feature to your geojson with the latitude and longitude like the do it in the [Leaflet GeoJSON Example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html).

Probably it will be more convenient to read the geometry.coordinates from geojson features and define a new marker.

Beside you have an error on line 569. You should change:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map','',{
```

to:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map',null,{
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I´ve corrected the error.
Can you give me an example, how to read the first geometry.coordinate from a geojson?

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple marker object and add it to the map.

```
marker = L.marker([0, 0], {
    icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon()
}).addTo(map)
```

Then set the latitude and longitude to the first coordinates of your geoJSON. Assuming your geoJSON is set to the var `geojson`, you can access the coordinates by indexing into the array.

```
marker.setLatLng(L.latLng(
    geojson.coordinates[0][1],
    geojson.coordinates[0][0]))
```

Comment: Thank´s for your advice, but i can´t get it up and running. I´ve updated some code, to show, how i create the polylines. Any suggestions, how i can use your code with this?

Comment: There's a couple of issues with your overall code, but it looks like you [already have a marker placed at the start in your geoJSON](http://geojson.io/#id=gist:geraldarthur/1e8ded31c020df48fba6&map=16/50.9043/7.4067). Line 524 leaves an open angle bracket with no closing brackets, and `onEachFeature2` is undefined. Please fix these issues first. If you're having difficulty, try this [CodeSchool course](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/) on how you can better diagnose and fix these bugs.